# Add markup inside a link (in the renderable array) in preprocess field

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

My question is for D8...

I have a field which is rendered as a link. Let say for simplicity that it will be rendered like this: `<a href="url">My Title</a>`

I would like to add a bootstrap icon inside the link to get a result like this: `<a href="url"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>My Title</a>`

I know that I can take the url and the title from within the preprocess function to reconstruct a new link (#markup)... But is it possible to simply add the icon code somewhere in the array to get the same result?

I am adding some more information to clarify:

1-The field which is rendered as a link is a term reference field rendered as a linked label

2-Here is my try in the preprocess_field function to achieve this

```
function mymodule_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  $fn = $vars['element']['#field_name'];
  switch ($fn) {
    case 'my_field':
      foreach ($vars['items'] as $key => $item) {
        $icon = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
        $vars['items'][0]['content']['#title']=$icon.$item['content']['#title'];
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [FormattableMarkup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21FormattableMarkup.php/class/FormattableMarkup/8.3.x) class for this:

```
$markup = new FormattableMarkup('<a href="@url"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true /></a>', [
          '@url' => $url->toString(), // If $url is an Drupal\Core\Url object.
        ]);

$renderArray['your_element'] = $markup;
```

**After edit:**

Use the [Markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Markup.php/class/Markup/8.3.x) class for this since your seem to be in control over your markup. If not use [FormattableMarkup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21FormattableMarkup.php/class/FormattableMarkup/8.3.x) with placeholders for safety:

```
  function mymodule_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
    $fn = $vars['element']['#field_name'];
    switch ($fn) {
      case 'my_field':
        foreach ($vars['items'] as $key => $item) {
          $icon = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
          $uri = $item['content']['#title'];

          $formattedIcon = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create($icon . $uri);

          $vars['items'][0]['content']['#title'] = $formattedIcon;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
```

From the [FormattableMarkup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21FormattableMarkup.php/class/FormattableMarkup/8.3.x) docs:

> When cast to a string, this object replaces variable placeholders in
>   the string with the arguments passed in during construction and
>   escapes the values so they can be safely displayed as HTML. See the
>   documentation of
>   \Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup::placeholderFormat() for
>   details on the supported placeholders and how to use them securely.
>   Incorrect use of this class can result in security vulnerabilities.

Comment: this is not really an answer to the question, as he does not want to add a new render element. but this is combinable with my answer!

Comment: It is an answer to the question. The variable `$renderArray` is just an example and could be replaced by any other variable or it could be directly assigned to the current render array.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, could you tell me where I have to "insert" `$markup` in my render array (see my updated question)

Comment: I guess in your `foreach()` loop: `$vars['items'][0]['content']['#title'] = $markup`.

Answer (score 2):

For the link field you can insert a markup-array in the title var, like this:

```
$icon = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
$variables['link_field_name']['title'] = [
  '#markup' => $icon . $variables['link_field_name']['title'],
];
```

**Edit:** For the term reference title use:

```
$vars['items'][0]['content']['#title'] = [
  '#markup' => $icon . $vars['items'][0]['content']['#title'],
];
```

Or like suggested from @Gun5m0k3 the new drupal 8 classy way:

```
$vars['items'][0]['content']['#title'] = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create($icon . $vars['items'][0]['content']['#title']);
```

Comment: Your second code part is incorrect: the second argument of the `FormattableMarkup` class is missing. Currently your code would emit a `TypeError`. If no placeholders have to be used and your inputted HTML is considered safe (no user input) you can also use the `Markup` class.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I have edited my question because I don't have `$variables['link_field_name']['title']` in my render array

Comment: @Gun5m0k3, true .. i was to quick ;)

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle this is to create an inline_template render item:

```
  function mymodule_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
    $fn = $vars['element']['#field_name'];
    switch ($fn) {
      case 'my_field':
        foreach ($vars['items'] as $key => $item) {
          $vars['items'][0]['content']['#title'] = [
            '#type' => 'inline_template',
            '#template' => '{{ icon }} {{ title }}',
            '#context' => [
              'icon' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
              'title' => $item['content']['#title'],
              ],
          ];
        }
        break;
    }
  }
```